# How to fix needing to restart program when updating a variable from another file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to make a game and when you Level up you unlock a mission and it works but I have to restart the program for it to unlock (level variable is in another file "save.py")

I've tried using importlib to restart save.py but that didn't work and also I tried to save the level up then restart save.py but that didn't work either

## Main File

```
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import *
from save import *


moneyvar = IntVar()
moneyvar.set(money)
moneyvariable = str(moneyvar)
levelvar = IntVar()
levelvar.set(level)
levelvariable = str(levelvar)

money = money + 100
level = level + 1
moneyvar.set(money)
levelvar.set(level)

def missions():
    missionbox = canvas.create_rectangle(0,0,700,650, fill = "#87ceeb")
    missiontext = canvas.create_text(350,50,font="arial 20 bold", text="Missions")
    backbtnmission = Button(text = "Back",font="arial 10 bold", bg="black", fg = "white", relief = FLAT, command = lambda: closemissions(missionbox, winm1, winm2, winb1, missiontext, winm3, winm4))
    winb1 = canvas.create_window(350, 80, window = backbtnmission)
    m1 = Button(text = "Tutorial",font="arial 10 bold", bg="black", fg = "white", relief = FLAT)
    winm1 = canvas.create_window(350, 110, window = m1)
    m2 = Button(text = "Locked",font="arial 10 bold", bg="black", fg = "white", relief = FLAT, state=DISABLED)
    winm2 = canvas.create_window(350, 140, window = m2)
    m3 = Button(text = "Locked",font="arial 10 bold", bg="black", fg = "white", relief = FLAT, state=DISABLED)
    winm3 = canvas.create_window(350, 170, window = m3)
    m4 = Button(text = "Locked",font="arial 10 bold", bg="black", fg = "white", relief = FLAT, state=DISABLED)
    winm4 = canvas.create_window(350, 200, window = m4)
    if level >=1:
        m2.configure(state = NORMAL, text = "Insert Mission Name Here")
    if level >=2:
        m3.configure(state = NORMAL, text = "Insert Mission Name Here")
    if level >=3:
        m4.configure(state = NORMAL, text = "Insert Mission Name Here")
```

## Save.py

```
money = 0
level = 0
```

I'm suppose to be able to just click on missions and see the next mission not disabled but I have to save and restart the program and then it is not disabled anymore

Thanks

Comment: Is that your main event loop?  Also can you show the rest of your imports.

Comment: Ok I will show the rest of my imports and that's the file that holds the game save.py is just to save your money and level so you can keep it next time you play again

Comment: Save data as data not a code. Use a JSON file or any other suitable format.

Answer (score 0):

You could try `importlib.reload`. For example,

```
.
├── dynamic
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── levels.py
├── __init__.py
└── reload_vals.py
```

reload_vals.py

```
from importlib import reload


def reload_vars():
    try:
        from dynamic import levels
        reload(levels)
        print(levels.level)
    except Exception as e:
        print('could not load module')
        print(e)


import time

if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        reload_vars()
```

levels.py

```
level = 102
```

This will reload new level values every second (assuming something else is updating `levels.py`. You could put a condition for reload instead.

**However, this is not a great approach.** Consider using a small database like SQLite for storing state of your game.

Comment: This doesn't work you can't use while loops in tkinter and from dynamic import levels ("save" for me) causes error "No Module named ''dynamic""

Comment: The code is just an example to show you how to reload modules at runtime. You do not need a loop, for example reload can be done at some point where you handle an event. May be I did not understand your question.

Comment: I said I tried using importlib to reload in the question but thank you anyway